# What type of woodworking clamp is this?

Tags: tools, woodworking

The pair of orange clamps are held onto a special mortising jig via threaded rod, the red inset image is a variation on the design but what are they called and where can you get them from?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This clamp is one type of a "Hold Down Clamp". Some types are direct bolt on clamps like this one:

[image]

Other types similar to the one that you pictured are designed to slip into the flanged head of a pin that pops up through a hole in the work bench.

[image]
Here is a picture of one in action where you can clearly see it engaging the pin coming up from the work surface. In this case notice that the work surface has an arrayed set of the attachment points.

[image]

When used on a work surface as shown above this type of clamp has a great advantage of being able to be used rotated around 360 degrees.

Be aware that this type of clamp has has dropped out of favor in more modern times and are hard to find. You could try [this link](http://www.toolbarn.com/jorgensen-1623.html?gclid=Cj0KEQjw7r-rBRDE_dXtgLz9-e4BEiQATeKG7LHE4_JKQK3XMuaUOM8TPq8klMH9mFIiwl3cCTLEf1UaAqVh8P8HAQ) or [this link](http://www.tools-plus.com/pony-1623.html?utm_medium=feed&utm_source=froogle&utm_term=PNY1623&gclid=Cj0KEQjw7r-rBRDE_dXtgLz9-e4BEiQATeKG7MVzyAOB5zLvAQCmP0pVmp3HvRCqZZK23ryCSQIwHrkaAqVr8P8HAQ).

---

The Original Hold Down Clamp (Holdfast), tap with a mallet to set, tap with a mallet to release.

[image]

Comment: Somewhat offtopic, what clamps or clamping methods have replaced its original utility?

Comment: @AdamDavis In the dog hole use-cases, holdfasts (which you set and release with a hammer) have started to surge in popularity due to their ease of use. In other applications, various types of quick clamps and gear clamps and cam clamps are popular. Various types of permanently-attached bench vises, as well as removable Moxon vises, are also popular.

Comment: Holdfasts, what's old is new again...

Comment: Thank you Michael, very through and helpful answer. The picture I posted was from an article in 'Fine Woodworking' where they are used to hold the item to be mortised with a plunge router.